Google Forms + App Script. Script will not validate answers for GRID
I have a script that runs on Google Forms. It is to look for multiple choice grids and transform them to multiple choice questions if rows or columns are > 3.
The form is set to one answer per row and an answer key is set.
Upon running the script, I get both "An error occurred: gridItem.getValidation is not a function" and "An error occurred: Invalid data updating form."
I want to script to transform grid items to multiple choice, retrieve correct answers from the answer key, limit choices to 3 (1 of 3 should be correct answer).
Adequate multiple choice questions are populating with 3 answer choices, but 1 of the 3 choices is usually not the correct answer.
Logs:
Jun 18, 2024, 10:50:15 AM   Info    Error updating grid item: gridItem.getValidation is not a function
Jun 18, 2024, 10:50:15 AM   Info    Error: gridItem.getValidation is not a function
        // Handle GRID items
        try {
          var gridItem = item.asGridItem();
          
          // Get rows and columns from the grid item
          var rows = gridItem.getRows();
          var columns = gridItem.getColumns();
          
          // Check if the grid item has 3 or fewer rows or columns
          if (rows.length <= 3 || columns.length <= 3) {
            continue; // Skip this grid item if it has 3 or fewer rows or columns
          }
          
          // Iterate over each column in the grid
          for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {
            // Create a new MultipleChoiceItem for each column
            var newMultipleChoiceItem = modifiedForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
            newMultipleChoiceItem.setTitle(columns[c]);
            
            // Prepare choices based on the grid options for the current column
            var choices = [];
            
            for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
              var answerText = gridItem.getValidation().getValidationForCell(r, c).getHelpText(); // Assuming the answer is stored in the help text
              var choiceText = rows[r] + ' - ' + answerText;
              var isCorrect = answerText === 'correct'; // Adjust as per your validation logic
              choices.push(newMultipleChoiceItem.createChoice(choiceText, isCorrect));
            }
            
            // Shuffle the choices
            choices = shuffleArray(choices);
            
            // Limit to 3 choices
            choices = choices.slice(0, 3);
            
            // Log choices before setting
            Logger.log('New multiple-choice item choices: ' + JSON.stringify(choices));
            
            // Set choices for the new MultipleChoiceItem
            newMultipleChoiceItem.setChoices(choices);
            Logger.log('New multiple-choice item created with choices: ' + JSON.stringify(choices));
          }
          
          // Remove the original GridItem from the form
          modifiedForm.deleteItem(item);
        } catch (e) {
          Logger.log('Error updating grid item: ' + e.message);
          throw e;
        }
      }
    }`
```


Upon running the script, I get both "An error occurred: gridItem.getValidation is not a function" and "An error occurred: Invalid data updating form."
The error message is generated because neither getValidation() nor getValidationForCell() exist.
How to get validation pattern from Google Form item explains it.
Having said that, the purpose of var answerText... is questionable since the only validation for a gridItem is whether to "require a limit of one response per column for a grid item". In any event, the help text (such as it is) can be retrieved using getHelpText() Doc ref.
